# Como puedo crear un proyecto MVC en Catalyst con Perl?

Tags: mvc, perl, raku

Requiero hacer un proyecto simple en **Catalyst** con **Perl MVC**, he investigado y no he visto tutoriales.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un tutorial en la propia documentación de Catalyst: [Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial).

También tienes mucha información [en su página oficial](http://www.catalystframework.org/).

Comment: Gracias amigo! @JoaquinFerrero

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [answer], el aporte queda corto en cuanto a contenido